# How to deploy to a secure(https) tomcat server using Jenkins?

Tags: azure, tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration, tomcat8

I want to set-up CI for one of my production servers. That server is HTTPS secured. However when Jenkins tries to deploy it gives me following exception:

```
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username you provided is not allowed to use the text-based Tomcat Manager (error 403)
```

The Tomcat server (8.x) is hosted on Azure Cloud on a Cent-OS based machine.
I've given following roles to the user in `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
roles="manager-jmx,manager-gui,manager-script,standard"
```

Is there any other role that is required to allow text-based access?

Comment: The Tomcat is enabled to connect with AJP protocol to using Apache HTTPD. It's HTTP protocol and port are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs  [https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html] you appear correct.

But based on the error message - it appears the text interface is being called. Which means you may need to add `manager-status` as a role.

Comment: I figured out that, if I enable HTTP protocol, I am able to deploy using Jenkins.